# How to create a comprehensively auditable database that is updated from multiple concurrent sources?

Tags: database-design, mysql-8.0

I have various different Python scripts running concurrently updating a MySQL database from a circa 15 API and web scraping sources. In another script a continuous loop runs that queries batches of data stored up until that point and then uses it for various calculations. If the output of the calculation meets certain criteria then I log the result in the database.

Every so often an unusual calculation output appears and I need to investigate whether this is a true result or if some erroneous data has crept in. To do this I need to be able to retrospectively run a query to extract the batch of data that generated a given calculation output. I can then check it manually.

However, currently the Python scripts can update existing records which makes auditing impossible because the base data for a calculation output could have changed since it was calculated.

For this issue I'm currently thinking I implement something along the lines of shadow tables as set out [here](https://vertabelo.com/blog/database-design-for-audit-logging/). My theory is that if I log the time i) any new record is created (`created_time`) and ii) a batch of data is extracted for a calculation (`batch_time`), then I can run a query to extract the latest versions of any records with a `created_time` prior to the `batch_time`.

My concern is that because I have scripts updating the database at the same time then there could be time conflicts. A potential example of a this step by step would be:

1. Record A is inserted into a table at `2022-04-14 11:13:59.0` (`created_time` stored as `2022-04-14 11:13:59`)
2. Record B is inserted into the same table at `2022-04-14 11:14:00.1` (`created_time` stored as `2022-04-14 11:14:00`)
3. A batch query is run at `2022-04-14 11:14:00.2` (`batch_time` recorded as `2022-04-14 11:14:00`)
4. Retrospective query run the following day to get all records prior to the `batch_time` of `2022-04-14 11:14:00`

In the above scenario then the batch query in 3 picks up both records A and B. However, the retrospective query in 4 only picks up record A.

The only two ways I could think of solving this potential issue were:

1. Run all the Python scripts sequentially. This isn't feasible as it would take too long - I need to be running calculations very frequently.
2. Store each batch of data in some way. This isn't feasible as the storage requirements are too great.

I guess I have a couple of questions:

1. Am I on the right track with this time based, shadow table approach or is there a better way to manage things?
2. Am I overthinking the issue with the 'time overlaps' or will this be a real issue?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is more commonly known as Change Tracking. Most database systems offer a form of it out of the box, but I'm not aware of MySQL offering it (though I'm no MySQL expert). Alternative to that, you could just add triggers to your tables that write the audit information you need to another table. Triggers are transactionally consistent, so I think that alleviates your *timing* concern if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) I'm pretty wedded to MySQL so will need to stick to that sadly. I've read up on triggers which are a neat concept I'd not heard of. However, could these not still result in a situation where a batch was extracted at `2022-04-14 11:14:00.2` which picked up a record created from a trigger at `2022-04-14 11:14:00.1`. However, as my timestamps are set to second precision then they would presumably both be logged as `2022-04-14 11:14:00`? If yes then this would mean that when I run a retrospective query for less than `batch_time` I will miss off the record?

Comment: Sorry I had a little bit of a tough time understanding the relationship of `created_time` to `batch_time` in your scenario. If you could maybe give an actual example as steps (bullet points) that outline the order of events simply, in your original post, that might help. But generally speaking, with a trigger you should not have the case where you log the write time of one record after a second record's write time, when that second record truly was written to the database after the first one. And you should be able to capture the write time to the precision of a millisecond, if not nanosecond.

Comment: Thanks again. Did my comment clear things up? I edited it after a few mins to make it clearer. So is the answer here is to increase the precision of my timestamps to minimise the potential for the 'rounding' issue to occur?

Comment: Sorry still not following exactly, I'd recommend giving a step by step example in your post. The "*write time*" I'm referring to is the literal event time of when the write occurred in your database and has nothing to do with what your `created_time` or `batch_time` fields say, nor what precision they are. Basically your trigger can audit the exact moment a write occurs to a table in your database, and that time can be whatever precision you want, independent of the precision of the time fields of your data.

Comment: Updated with a step by step example. Hope that helps? The challenge for me is how to be able to run a retrospective query that extracts the same data as the original query that generates the calculation output.

Comment: Yes that's clearer now, thanks!! I'll analyze it in depth when I get a chance and will get back to you.

Comment: I think really what your process should incorporate (from a good relational perspective) is way to relate the records that get processed to the batch that processes them. That may just be simply having a nullable `batch_id` column in your table with the raw records. When the batch query in step 3 is ran, it gets logged to a `Batches` table to generate the unique `batch_id` (can be an identity column), and then updates your raw records table with that `batch_id` for the records it's about to process. This removes any time ambiguity for when you need to look back retrospectively.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! The challenge with a `batch_id` is that any batch can overlap a previous batch so a single column wouldn't suffice. That said, a unique sequential identifier is definitely the way to go and I've settled on a solution from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/125900/11277108.

Comment: No problem. I was waiting to see if you'd say that was the case. In that case you'd just create a linking table instead that allows such a many-to-many relationship to be established. It would contain the key of your raw data table and the key of the `Batches` table (`batch_id`). So the same raw record could appear in that linking table multiple times across different batches. Then you'd be able to go from any batch that ran, to all the raw records it encompassed, even when multiple batches re-processed the same records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135566/discussion-between-j-d-and-jossy).